# Busybox env does not show LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

We are using linux on an embedded system that has busybox 1.20.2 for the various shell commands. We are having a very strange problem in that env does now show the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PAT=/usr/bin
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH1=/usr/bin
$ env | sort
ENV=/etc/profile.environment
HISTFILE=/tmp/.ash_history.debug.357
HOME=/home/debug
LD_LIBRARY_PAT=/usr/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH1=/usr/bin
LOGNAME=debug
MAIL=/var/mail/debug
PATH=/home/debug/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/home/debug
PYTHONPATH=:/home/debug/tools/tools-0.0.0/common
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=10.10.10.22 58307 22
SSH_CONNECTION=10.10.10.22 58307 10.10.12.23 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TERM=xterm
USER=debug
_=/usr/bin/env
$ 
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PAT
/usr/bin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH1
/usr/bin
```

As you can see, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set, but it just doesn't show up in the output of env. AFAIK, it is the only environment variable that this happens.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Weird question...  Does it work as root?

Comment: Can you test with something other than `env`? python or perl or something to see if that inherits `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly? Could busybox be explicitly disallowing export of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for some reason?

Answer (score 6):

[Linux won't let you mess with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310583/program-cant-load-after-setting-the-setuid-bit-on) because busybox (probably) has its setuid bit turned on.  Busybox has a bunch of common linux commands built into its binary, so it needs setuid.